# EXCEL table linked to WORD overwrites WORD table properties

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-word-2010

I have 30 EXCEL tables - Linked with Formatting - into 8 WORD documents.
I would like the Table Properties ROW in the WORD document to **Repeat Header** and **Not allow row to break across pages**.
This is easy to setup in the WORD document, but ***disappears*** when the WORD doc is updated from EXCEL.

The options I have for Paste link:
1. Microsoft Excel Worksheet (code) Object  
2. Unformatted Text  
3.  Picture (Windows Metafile)  
4.  Bitmap  
5. Word Hyperlink  
6. HTML Format  
7. Unformatted Unicode Text
I need a link that pulls the table over unformatted, so that I can change the table properties in the WORD document and have them stay when the linked data is updated. (???)

Comment: Yes, because you told it to by have it *Linked with Formatting*. Did you have a question?

Comment: @CharlieRB  Tried the **Micorsoft Excel Worksheet (code) Object** and it worked. The questions is how to not have to Re-Link the 30 EXCEL tables in 8 documents without formatting.   Is there a way to just change the properties on the currently linked tables ?

Comment: @CharlieRB  Actually it did not work.  Which Unformatted version can I paste as a linked table so that it will not overwrite the WORD table properties ?    That is my question.   Thanks, Ed..

Comment: Please add those details and the question to your post by using the [edit] link.